# Rails How To replace Relation#first with scope first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've upgraded form Rails 3.2.12 to Rails 4.0.0, now I'm fixing all the deprecation warnings.

one of those is:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#first with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call #first on it instead.
```

the code looks like this:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.first :conditions => ["id = ?", session[:user_id]]
end
```

how can I replace this with scope? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general pointer, the conditions syntax is discouraged, use where instead.

However in your case it looks as though you are querying a primary key so you could simply use find:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

If you want to change some of your other queries such as:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["active = ?", true])
```

This would be changed to

```
@users = User.where(:active => true)
```

or in ruby 1.9

```
@users = User.where(active: true)
```

To more fully answer your question about scopes.  You can define scopes on a model, for example to find all active users:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

Then you could call `User.active`. You can also pass a parameter into a scope so as a proof of concept, you could do the following to find an active user by a given ID:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active_by_id, ->(id) { active.find(id) }
end
```

Then call `User.active_by_id(session[:user_id])`

Read more about Active Record Scopes : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: why do you use @users instead of @current_user?

Comment: your solution dosn't work for me only `@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])` works

Comment: This will only work if id (which it should be) is defined as primary key, otherwise use `find_by`

Answer (score 1):

`User.where(id: session[:user_id]).first`

if id is primary key you can use just

`User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])`

Comment: is it correct this way: `@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])`

Comment: yes that is how you should use it. I skiped the `@current_user ||=`

Comment: but if you want strictly exact behavior - use  `User.where(id: session[:user_id]).first` because `find_by` is implemented as  `where(*args).take` but `take` does not necessary returns first